# Processing large file using java

Tags: java

Updated:

My requirement is to process files with huge content. I need to apply multiple business rules on the file content. The business rule may be applicable on the whole content of the file. For example based on the status of a column, it becomes eligible for a business rule. Outcome of one business rule will be eligible for another business rule.

Another requirement is to apply quality checks on the incoming data in the form of files. In many cases, i see that i have to store large content in memory for processing.

---

I was going through [this article](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/processing-huge-files-with-java.html) which was explaining on how to process a large file using java.nio package. I found this very interesting and thought of trying this code.

Unfortunately, the code is not executable. Can somebody help me in sharing/making the executable code for this? Clues of how to make this executable are also welcome.

Issues i found are:

1. The method closeQuietly(InputStream) in the type Closeables is not applicable for the arguments (FileChannel)
2. Could not figure out what should be the Timestamped implementation (blog claims this file is not shown there)!
3. TrueFxDecoder and TrueFxData are missing!! A dummy implementation reference will be of great help.

Libraries used: JavaSE-1.7, Guava-17.0.jar

I believe, this executable code definitely useful to many other people who are in need of this kind of requirement.

Comment: For the purpose you describe, the tutorial you found is just too complicated. Try finding a way simpler example for this. Opening and processing huge files can be done in Java in about 10 lines of code.

Comment: Morevoer, this can be achieved with traditional InputStreams. The author of the tutorial is wrong in stating this was not possible. In fact, it's a very standard thing to do with streams.

Comment: I strongly recommend using a better tutorial.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve in the first place. The task cannot be done by reading the file in a line-wise mode for example? You need to read the whole file for some reason? If you were more specific it could be easier for people to help you

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Body is down :( for health reasons. I have updated the question for better clarity on requirement.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, BufferedInputStream and BufferedOutputStream are great for processing large files, since these streams don't load the whole file into memory, they use an internal buffer. This tutorial you have chosen is quite complex and confusing.